# Как сделать так чтобы файлик читался НЕ асинхроннно?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать так чтобы файлик читался **НЕ** асинхроннно? Это очень важно для моей системы я на этим голову сломал

```
    public void Load_Desgin(string dir_name)
{
    clear_garadge();
    string data = File.ReadAllText("Data/" + dir_name + "/save.json");
    SaveGame sg = new SaveGame();
    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(data, sg);
    details = sg.details;
    for (int j = 0; j < details.Length; j++)
    {
        Save_base sb = new Save_base();
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(details[j], sb);
        gm = Instantiate(dm.Get_GameObject_from_ID(sb.id));
        gm.GetComponent<Detail>().car = gameObject;
        gm.GetComponent<Save_base>().Set_parametrs(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: вы уже читаете файл синхронно (в строчке №4)

Comment: Я читаю его асинхронно это 100%, потому что это растягивается на несколько кадров в юнити

Comment: как же, вы на выход *сразу* получаете результат считывания

Comment: "Opens a binary file, reads the contents of the file into a byte array, and then closes the file."

Comment: скорее всего сам метод `Load_Design` вызывается параллельно основному потоку.

Comment: Сним явно что-то не так т к если добавить после вызова метода несколько yeild return null; , то всё работает

Comment: @return как избежать параллельного вызова Load_Design?

Comment: `Load_Design` вызывается вами? Если да, то нужно посмотреть на вызов этого метода.

Comment: @return 
Вызывается он в таком блоке 
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(-3f, 10.5f, 34.33f);
            GameObject bot_pref = bot_prefs[Random.Range(0, bot_prefs.Length)];
            gm = Instantiate(bot_pref, pos, bot_pref.transform.rotation);
            gm.GetComponent<SaveGame>().Load_Desgin("UserBluePrint(2)");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f); если метод будет просто void, то неработает
            _Z = _Z - 20;
            pos = new Vector3(Spawn_Pos_B.position.x, Spawn_Pos_B.position.y, _Z);
            gm.transform.position = pos;

Comment: т.е. ваш метод возвращает `IEnumerable<WaitForSeconds>`, и вы используете `yield`?

Comment: если так, то тело метода вызывается только после вызова `MoveNext`: `var enumerable = ВашМетод(); enumerable.MoveNext() /* вызывается тело метода */;`. Или в цикле `foreach`: `foreach (var wait in ВашМетод()) { ... } /* каждую итерацию вызывается MoveNext */`.

Comment: Сначала метод был void, но потом чтобы как-то работало я добавил IEnumerator   и yeild return. Так что не смотрите

Comment: Попробуйте использовать отладку: остановитесь на месте строчки со считыванием файла и посмотрите на трассировку стека. Возможно, где-то выше был вызван метод, запускающий вашу операцию параллельно.

Comment: Так вызывайте метод не из корутины, а например из Awake или Start. Кстати код корутины перенесите в сам вопрос. Его можно редактировать.

Comment: `Я читаю его асинхронно это 100%`, вы его читаете в отдельном потоке, это к асинхронности не имеет отношения. Это многопоточность. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: @aepot лично меня очень сильно смущает, что когда он перешёл на `yield`, то всё заработало (не параллельно, а синхронно). что же у него там уровнем выше...